# Matching Uppercase/lowercase pairs with sed

Tags: sed, patterns, case

Can I write a pattern in `sed` that matches patterns like *Aa*, *Bb*, *Cc*, etc. (i.e., Given an uppercase letter, it should match the corresponding lowercase letter) without enumerating all possibilities?

Comment: Can you give a sample of input/output...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`, you can do:

```
$ echo 'fooÉébAar' | perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/([[:upper:]])(??{lc$^N})/<$&>/g'
foo<Éé>b<Aa>r
```

That uses the `(??{code})` special perl operator, where you can dynamically specify the regexp to match on. Here `lc$^N` is the lowercase version of `$^N`, the last capture group.

With GNU `sed`, you could do:

```
$ echo 'fooÉébAar' | sed -Ee 's/./&\L&/g;s/([[:upper:]](.)\2.)/<<\1>>/g;s/(.)./\1/g'
foo<Éé>b<Aa>r
```

The idea is that we first append each character in the input with their lower case version (`X` becomes `Xx`, `x` becomes `xx`), so if we see a `Xxx` after that (`([[:upper:]](.)\2`: `X` followed a repeated character), that means we've got an uppercase character followed by its lower case version.

Note that those would not work for characters in decomposed form. For instance for `É` when expressed as `E` followed by a *combining acute accent*. To work around that you could use `perl`'s `\X` graphem cluster regexp operator instead:

```
$ printf 'E\u0301\u0302\u00e9\u0302 \u00c9e\u301 foo Ee\u301\n' |
   perl -Mopen=locale -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '
     s/((?=[[:upper:]])\X)(?{$c1 = $^N})(\X)(??{
       NFD(lc$c1) eq NFD($^N) ? qr{} : qr{(?!)}})/<$&>/g'
<É̂é̂> <Éé> foo Eé
```

Above using *canonical normalisation forms* (`NFD`) so that graphem clusters are always represented in the same way at the character level.

It would still fail to match on things like `Fﬃ` where that `ﬃ` (U+FB03) is a single (typographical ligature) character but that's probably just as well anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Sed* in combination with *Bash* or *Zsh*, you can just use a small *meta-program*, like that:

**Code**

```js
>echo "AaBCAABbEE"| sed -E "s/`echo {A..Z}|sed -E 's/\w/&\L&/g;y/ /|/'`/%/g"
%BCAA%EE
```

This will effectively generate all the combinations for you, using shell brace expansion (and nested *sed*), like illustrated below:

```js
>echo {A..Z}|sed -E 's/\w/&\L&/g;y/ /|/'        
Aa|Bb|Cc|Dd|Ee|Ff|Gg|Hh|Ii|Jj|Kk|Ll|Mm|Nn|Oo|Pp|Qq|Rr|Ss|Tt|Uu|Vv|Ww|Xx|Yy|Zz
```

There are probably some pure-Sed ways of doing this too, e.g. by applying several substitutions in a row and/or using a hold space to search for these pairs one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Combining bash and sed (in this example i use sed to match and delete the letters):

```
$ word="Hey , This is AaBbCc and also Dd!"

$ search="H";search2=${search,,};sed "s/[$search$search2]//g" <<<"$word"
ey , Tis is AaBbCc and also Dd!

$ search="A";search2=${search,,};sed "s/[$search$search2]//g" <<<"$word"
Hey , This is BbCc nd lso Dd!

$ search="D";search2=${search,,};sed "s/[$search$search2]//g" <<<"$word"
Hey , This is AaBbCc an also !
```

You just need to provide the search letter in uppercase at var "search=".

PS: If you need to search for lowercase letters then those can be transformed to uppercase with `${search^^}`

Comment: Your pattern patches `either` the upper or lower case letter.  The OP wanted to match the pair.  So the `[` and `]` should not be in your sed pattern.